# How to get number of friends added by facebook user in the specific time of period?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We need to get number of friends added by Facebook user in last month. We have searched in the Graph API,but didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use FQL notification.
But notification actually are limited to last 7 days.

Try this query:

```
SELECT created_time, sender_id, title_html, href, object_type
FROM notification
WHERE recipient_id=me() and object_type = 'friend'
```

**Update:**

Another approach, a little bit tricky.
You should be able to have a look at older friendship into your `stream`:

```
SELECT created_time, description FROM stream WHERE source_id = me()
and (strpos(lower(description),'are now friends') > 0 
    or strpos(lower(description),'is now friends') > 0) 
limit 50
```

In this way you get all rows containing the sentences `are now friends` or `is now friends`, (note that sentences words depends from customer(?) locale settings). So you'll match all rows:

- X and Y are now friends
- X is now friends with X and Y...

> Each query of the stream table is limited to the previous 30 days or 50 posts, whichever is greater, however you can use time-specific fields such as created_time along with FQL operators (such as < or >) to retrieve a much greater range of posts.
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

**Update 2:**

If you want use only graph api, as far I know you have same limitation of fql (i.e. you're limited to last 7 days).

https://graph.facebook.com/me/notifications?include_read=1

But this case, you cannot filter for `object_type` and you must find all `title` containings `"accepted your friend request"`

Comment: We are using graph api,Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this..
$count=0;
$fbid=xxxxx;
$onemonthbefore = strtotime(date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 Months")));
$ss=urlencode("SELECT created_time,description_tags,source_id,description FROM     stream    WHERE source_id = xxxxxx and (strpos(lower(description),'are now friends') > 0  or strpos(lower(description),'is now friends') > 0) limit 100");
$sql="https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=$ss&access_token=xxxxxxxxx&format=json&  date_format=U";
$new    =file_get_contents($sql);
$new    =json_decode($new);
foreach ($new->data as $data)
{
  if($data->created_time > $onemonthbefore)
  {
    foreach ($data->description_tags as $tags)
    {

   foreach ($tags as $friend)
   {
     if($friend->id !=$fbid)
      {
         $count++;
      }
   }
}
}
}
echo "new friends=".$count;
```